# List Opearation

Tags: r, list

I am trying to perform a loop operation on the items of a list and while it seeems simple enough, I am not getting the expected solution due to a bug I can't detect. the code is:

```
multinoms<- list() ###Empty list for storing computed multinomial densities
 for (l in 1:length(sampled_geno)){
   for (i in 1:length(sampled_geno[1])){
     b <- as.data.frame(table(sampled_geno[i]))
    multinoms[l] <-dmultinom(x=c(b$Freq[1], b$Freq[2], b$Freq[3]), prob= c(b$Freq[1]/sum(b$Freq),b$Freq[2]/sum(b$Freq),b$Freq[3]/sum(b$Freq)))
   }
 }
```

Sampled_geno is a list of lenght 5.  Using my code, I only get one computed density repeated 5 times although the list values are different as we see below.

```
[[1]]
 [1] 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 1
[47] 2 2 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
[93] 0 2 1 1 1 0

[[2]]
 [1] 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 1
[47] 2 2 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 1
[93] 0 0 0 1 0 0

[[3]]
 [1] 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 1
[47] 2 2 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
[93] 1 0 0 0 1 1

[[4]]
 [1] 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 1
[47] 2 2 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 2 2 0
[93] 0 0 1 0 0 1

[[5]]
 [1] 1 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 1
[47] 2 2 1 2 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 0 1 0 2 2 0
[93] 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Any help is really appreciated.

```r
sampled_geno <- list(c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,  1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), c(1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: (1) I added a usable sample of `sampled_geno`, please confirm it's what you expect. If not, please fix it. (2) `length(sampled_geno[1])` is always 1, since `[` on a list always returns a list. Perhaps you mean `length(sampled_geno[[1]])`? Similarly, `sampled_geno[i]`. (3) Once you fix that, this fails more clearly, since using `i` extends too far with `table(sampled_geno[[i]])` when `i` is 6 or more. Do you intend to use `sampled_geno[[l]]` ("ell", not "eye") instead?

Comment: FYI, you can significantly reduce your `x`= to `x=b$Freq`, and your `prob=` down to just `b$Freq/sum(b$Freq)`.

Comment: @r2evans, yes my major mistake was using the single brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sampled_geno` use `[[ ]]` instead of `[]` to access the list element.

```
for (l in 1:length(sampled_geno)){
  b <- as.data.frame(table(sampled_geno[[l]]))
  multinoms[[l]] <- dmultinom(x=c(b$Freq[1], b$Freq[2], b$Freq[3]), prob= c(b$Freq[1]/sum(b$Freq),b$Freq[2]/sum(b$Freq),b$Freq[3]/sum(b$Freq)))
}
```

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.009551857

[[2]]
[1] 0.009774618

[[3]]
[1] 0.009624812

[[4]]
[1] 0.009718148

[[5]]
[1] 0.009416344
```

Comment: Thank you @Tarjae,  this fixed it. I had the double brackets around it before but I thought accessing list elements could work with either a single or double bracket.